# Replace System Default Emoji with Twitter Emoji in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, emoji

I want to convert the system default emoji to Twitter emoji. I implemented an emoji picker in my web application and when I select any emoji from the emoji tray then that will be appears based on system OS in the textarea.
if I used windows then emoji appears in the textarea based on windows if I used Linux then that appears based on Linux.

But what I want that Twitter emoji should appear in textarea irrespective of OS.

Comment: whats a *Twitter emoji*?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Twitter emoji simply means Twitter emoji set. you can search twitter/twemoji then you will able to know about twitter emoji.

Comment: ok, then use twitters sprites

Comment: @LawrenceCherone what do you mean by Twitter sprites. I used the emoji picker jQuery library in the application.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Masood I am stuck and looking for solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by replacing emoji characters with images (`<img>`) from Twitter's emoji library.
I would give a code sample but I'm not very experienced and I'm not sure of an efficient way to do this, so this is the best answer I can really give.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want that Twitter emoji should appear in textarea irrespective
> of OS.

Ignoring if this is allowed by [twitters branding protection](https://about.twitter.com/en/who-we-are/brand-toolkit) or [tos](https://twitter.com/en/tos).

Twitter use svg images, so unless your lib allows for changing urls or defining the template of rendered dom or parsing, your need to parse the input for emojis and convert the matched value to obtain the unicode i.e:  into `U+1F60F` then remove the `U+` and lowercase, which then you can use to display an image:  https://abs-0.twimg.com/emoji/v2/svg/1f60f.svg

Sidenote, you cant display images in textarea's